# Tab slide out plugin programmatically slide in

Tags: jquery, slide

I am using this plugin: [TabSlideOut jquery Plugin](http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/) to slide make a tab slide out.

However is there any way to trigger the tab panel to slide in through code?

There is a button in the tab  panel and upon clicking that I do some ajax processing after which I want the panel to close automatically if successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like the plugin has a close method. You can simply simulate a click on the success call back of your ajax call. Where `.handle` is the handle element you passed in to your TabSlideOut plugin

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.handle').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. This worked for me perfectly. Didn't know that it would be that easy!!!